# What concept does a natural transformation between two functors between two monoids viewed as categories correspond to?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, semigroups, monoid

Let $\mathcal{M}$ be the monoid $M$ viewed as a category (single object, arrows are elements of $M$) and similarly for $\mathcal{N}$ and N.

Let $F : M \to N$, and $G : M \to N$ be two monoid homomorphisms which are also functors from $\mathcal{M} \to \mathcal{N}$.  Then a natural transformation from $F \implies G$ is an element $\psi_N \in N$ such that $\psi_N \cdot F(a) = G(a) \cdot \psi_N, \ \forall a \in M$ where $\cdot$ is the monoid law of $N$.

Then what monoid-theoretic concept does this natural transformation correspond to?  I've never seen it before.

Comment: At least for groups, this would correspond to $F$ and $G$ being related by conjugation. (i.e. more precisely, being related by post-composition with an inner automorphism)

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/56949/natural-transformations-in-a-group-category?rq=1